# Does the maiden over includes extras?

Tags: cricket, terminology

Today, Malinga bowled an over with 4 leg-byes, but it was given a maiden over.
Then I searched about that and got the details as,

> If a bowler delivers a complete over without a run being scored from
>   the bat (even though the opponents may have scored extras by means of
>   byes or leg byes), he has achieved a maiden over. - [Source](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/358427/maiden-over).

I have a doubt, if the bowler bowls a wide or no-ball, will it be considered as a maiden?

The above statement only states about byes or leg-byes, wides and no-balls are also considered as extras. The wide can't be dealt with bat, but a no-ball can get contact with the bat.

So, the clear question is,

What are all the requirements for a maiden over?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wides and no-balls are known as *bowling extras* and are counted against the bowler (think of the bowler being at fault for them), and therefore an over that includes any bowling extras cannot be a maiden over.

Byes and leg-byes are, by contrast, known as *fielding extras* (think of the fielders being at fault - the wicketkeeper failing to take the ball, for instance) and do not count against the bowler, so a maiden over may include byes and leg-byes.

A maiden over, in short, is an over containing neither any runs off the bat nor any bowling extras (wides and no-balls).

*Tom Smith's Umpiring and Scoring* (one of the foremost, possibly the foremost, reference books on umpiring and scoring in cricket) [has this to say](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=M9O1rJfNOGUC&pg=PT187&lpg=PT187&dq=tom%20smith%27s%20cricket%20umpiring%20and%20scoring%20maiden&source=bl&ots=UNMCHdRI0q&sig=9URTOyM5WveSPzQk_AJx0aM7Arg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=b0W8UfKsIMmt0QWsmoGoCg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA):

> A maiden over is one where no runs are conceded by the bowler, i.e. the striker has no scored any runs and there have been no bowling extras (No balls or Wides). It may include fielding extras (Byes, Leg byes or penalty runs).

Answer (score -2):

Maiden over means,no runs in an over.
it should not come from either bat or extras.

Answer (score -3):

Maiden Over is the one in which the bowler bowls only 6 deliveries.

which will count out the wides and no-balls ("bowling extras")being bowled, causing the bowler to bowl an extra delivery

So a maiden over can have extras (byes and leg byes- "fielding extras")

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to Spinner's nearly two year old answer.