# First Maiden Over in T20 Cricket

Tags: cricket, trivia

I want to know Who bowled the first **Maiden Over** in T20 (Twenty over match) cricket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first ever maiden over of T20I was bowled by Mohammad Asif at the eighth T20I match.

It was a [double wicket maiden over](http://www.espncricinfo.com/engvpak/engine/match/225263.html?bowler=19627;innings=1;view=commentary) with a leg-bye run which may not considered in [a maiden over](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/does-the-maiden-over-includes-extras).

Answer (score 1):

Since OP specified T20 cricket (rather than just T20I) the first ever maiden over was bowled by Ian Hunter on 13 June 2003 whose figures were 4-1-21-1 for [Durham vs. Nottinghamshire](https://pcboard.com.pk/Nottinghamshire/Scorecards/77/77122.html).